# WP user registration - can also choose his/her password right away

Tags: php, wordpress, registration

Here's a very short guide for front-end registration but Im having a small problem with password.

**I disabled the email with password generation that gets sent if user registers:**

```
//Don't Send Notification Email To Registered User
if (!function_exists('wp_new_user_notification')) :
function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $notify = '' ) {

//Here's originally password generation + sending email
//Add greeting email later

}
endif;
```

- User gets no email when registered
- Yes, it's added by plugin because pluggable.php can only be overwritten from plugin

---

**My front-end register form (don't mind that "repeat password" is missing - just for testing):**

```
        <?php if( get_option('users_can_register') ) { ?>

                    <form name="registerform" id="registerform" action="<?php echo wp_registration_url(); ?>" method="post">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="user_pass" id="user_pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>  

                        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo site_url(); ?>?user-register=registered">
                        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit-registration" id="wp-submit-registration" value="<?php _e( 'Register', 'tt' ); ?>">
                    </form>

        <?php } ?>
```

**QUESTION: Why doesn't it save password on user registration?**

- Everything else besides password works - user gets registered & correct data is inserted
- Do I use wrong keyword somewhere (user_pass)?
- Could it be that password can't be set with original wp_registration_url()?
- If that's the case, should/and how should I use wp insert user()?

**I would also appriciate if someone threw in a link how to add WP password strength indicator because I didn't find any tuts.**

Comment: What's your question, how to encrypt a password to use it in WP?

Comment: My solution doesn't save password for some reason. Question is: **why's that so?**

Comment: It's you! My post delete timer works great, switched to server cron & made few other changes, thanks for that! Now this problem.. I looked into database & **the problem seems to be that it sets "default_password_nag" to 1 (true)**. I somehow need to stop that.

Comment: Glad it worked :) For your registration issue, I'm not sure if this should work at all. Does the user are added in the database? The default wordpress register form doesn't have any password field, so you need to create a custom form and action. I'm writing an answer to share some code I used for that before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code shouldn't work at all, password or not. First thing, [`wp_registration_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_registration_url) return the url of the default registration form. For a custom registration form, you can submit your form to `admin-post.php` with as custom action name like `register_user`:

```
<form name="registerform" id="registerform" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php?action=register_user'); ?>" method="post">
```

For security I highly recommend you to add this in your form (it will generate [an hidden input](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) with a token to check that the action has been initiated by the user:

```
wp_nonce_field('create-'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 'user-front', false);
```

Then in your *functions.php* file you hook on that with `admin_post_nopriv_register_user`.

```
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_register_user', 'my_register_user');
function my_register_user() {
    // Check the form validity
    if (isset($_POST['user-front']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['user-front'], 'create-'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {

        // Check the required field
        if (!isset($_POST['user_login']) && !isset($_POST['user_email']) || !isset($_POST['user_pass']) || !isset($_POST['user_confirm_pass']) || !is_email($_POST['user_email'])
            ) {
            wp_redirect(home_url() . '?message=wrong-input');
            exit();
        }

        // Check if both password match
        if ($_POST['user_pass'] != $_POST['user_confirm_pass']) {
            wp_redirect(home_url() . '?message=pass-dif');
            exit();
        }

        // Check if user exists
        if (email_exists($_POST['user_email']) |- username_exists($_POST['user_login']) {
            wp_redirect(home_url() . '?message=already-registered');
            exit();
        }

        // Create the user
        $user_id = wp_create_user($_POST['user_login'], $_POST['user_pass'], $_POST['email_user']);
        $user = new WP_User($user_id);
        $user->set_role('subscriber');

        // Automatic loggin
        $creds = array();
        $creds['user_login'] = $_POST['user_login'];
        $creds['user_password'] = $_POST['user_pass'];
        $creds['remember'] = false;
        $user = wp_signon($creds, false);

        // Redirection
        wp_redirect(home_url('account'));
        exit();
    }
}
```

This is a complete example of a registration process, you may want to change this a bit depending of your needs (specially how the errors are handled).

Comment: I'll see what I can do to integrate your solution with mine. Note that I don't want to lose jQuery Validation - its super easy to work with & lets me easily to add AJAX username/email check in future. Meanwhile could you look at my question again? I added something for you.

Comment: @AWA Well you can totally keep your JS validation layer, but keep the PHP validation as well - so if user disable javascript you still check his form inputs. I don't think you can workaround the need to a custom function to insert the new user, as by default Wordpress doesn't expect the password to be sent. An other good thing for using a custom registration function is that if you need later to add some other inputs in your form (like firstname, lastname etc) you can easily handle this by adding custom usermeta. Let me know if you stumble on something.

Comment: Yeah.. I've restricted access to wp-admin for everyone but admin (throws 404) & replaced wp-login with secret URL. Unfortunately this solution uses wp-admin. Don't ask me why but my old login/register didn't conflict with wp-login/wp-admin. Im wondering if there's a work-around.

Comment: Im currently finding a way to make an exeption to this action but there's still one question: is it as safe as "original" register.. or login if I choose to use this method to login too?

Comment: As long you're using the token ("nonce") to check the form validity it's safe - it still use the regular WP function to create the user. Just don't forget the nonce and to check the validity of user input in PHP, even if you're doing a JS validation. About your `wp-admin` restriction, you can probably make an exception for `admin-post.php` (if you did it through htaccess you could do a `RewriteCond`).