# Secure way to let user create their own password with ACF registration form in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, security, passwords, registration

I'm looking to allow a user to create their own password on a custom front-end registration form.

I've created a front-end user registration form with ACF.

Currently the password is generated on the backend like so:

```
$password = wp_generate_password( 10, true, false );

$userdata = array(
    'user_login' => $email,
    'user_email' => $email,
    'display_name' =>  $display_name,
    'user_pass' =>  $password,
    'role' => 'puppydog',
);

$created_user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
```

It's a simple thing to do grab a password field from the front-end, but I'm wondering if it's safe to just take that password field, escape & hash it, and store it in the database? Or is there a more secure way to do it?

I noticed [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495899/wp-user-registration-can-also-choose-his-her-password-right-away) seems to just take the password from the front-end and create a user with it "raw," but I want to make sure this is actually reasonably safe to do?